# MongoDB Loop: Saving data from variable?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, loops, variables, mongoose

Working with a frontend variable like below in javascript with many objects... (Note - the scores would be different for each user therefore **I would need to be able to get the info from the frontend**)

```
var campgrounds = [{ name: "State Park #1" score: 0, }, { name: "State Park #2" score: 0, }, { name: "State Park #3" score: 0 }]
```

How would I be able to store that data in MongoDB? Could I somehow loop through the data? Or could I store the entire variable "campgrounds" in Mongo? like `$("#quizData").value(campgrounds)`

Would I set up a Schema like below? Even if I did I'm not sure how to actually get the data in the variable into Mongo. Not sure how to accomplish my goal.  Thanks for any help! :)

```
var campgroundsSchema = new Schema ({
    "campgrounds" : [{
      name : {type: String},
      score : {type : Number}
    }],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you connect to mongo using mongoshell ...

```
mongo --host localhost:27017
```

you can issue the following javascript commands...

```
use campgroundsdb
var campgrounds = [{ name: "State Park #1", score: 0 }, { name: "State Park #2", score: 0, }, { name: "State Park #3", score: 0 }]
db.campgroundscollection.insertMany(campgrounds)
```

Then find them by issuing...

```
db.campgroundscollection.find().pretty()
```

If you want to create a program written in JavaScript it will need the ability to connect to the mongodb process.  Node.js tutorials fit this requirement...

https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp

Comment: Thanks for the help! Would this work with the campgrounds variable having data that changes based on user input on the front end? Thats my main blocker :)

Comment: As long as the data provided by the users can be stored in a JavaScript variable it can be saved into Mongo.  There is a 16MB limit on how much data can be saved in one document.  Thats a large amount of data so it usually isn't much of a limit.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you for the help!